# how to ignore space in sql search query?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a SQL table which has a column entry of an IP Address like `5.  5. 44.  4` .
That is `5.<space><space>5.<space>44.<space><space>4`

I have a query to search for this ip address like

```
select dns_name from toms_table where ip_address like '%5.5.44.4%'
```

But this is not listing the dns_name only because of the space in ipaddress.

How can indicate in sql query to ignore the space in table entries while searching ?

Comment: Why have you tagged two *completely different* products? Which product are you *actually* using?

Comment: @Stu Im using mysql

Comment: Then please don't tag a completely unrelated, but conflicting, product @mac. Adding irrelevant tags makes your question unclear.

Comment: Sounds like you need a *replace()* function, the MySql documentation seems to indicate there is one; I would fix your data and validate/correct the data on insert.

Comment: What does your actual datable table column look like? I'm curious why you're using `like`. Try `select dns_name from toms_table where replace(ip_address, " ", "") = '5.5.44.4';`

Comment: You can try something like `WHERE ip_address REGEXP '^5[. ]+5[. ]+44[. ]+4$'` (not tested)

Comment: `UPDATE toms_table SET ip_address = REPLACE(ip_address, ' ','')` Then you can just check for equality `SELECT dns_name FROM toms_table WHERE ip_address = '5.5.44.4'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all characters that you don't need or want with REPLACE

If the ip adress only consist of '5.  5. 44.  4' with out additional characters, you don't need the %, mysql wouldn't use the index on  that table, which would increase the speed of the query

```
CREATE tABLE toms_table (ip_address varchar(100), dns_name varchar(4))
```

```
INSERT INTO toms_table VALUES ('5.  5. 44.  4','test')
```

```
select dns_name from toms_table where REPLACE(ip_address, ' ','') like '%5.5.44.4%'
```

| dns_name |
| --- |
| test |

```
select dns_name from toms_table where REPLACE(ip_address, ' ','') like '5.5.44.4'
```

| dns_name |
| --- |
| test |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OjB0xmIA)

Comment: While you can utilize the REPLACE() function, it's actually more efficient to sanitize the input before creating the query. Consider this scenario: if you're dealing with a large dataset, like one million records, and you're asking the database to clean up each field before comparing, it could result in a significant waste of CPU resources. To streamline this process, handle the sanitization of the input before query. This approach minimizes the burden on the database server, makes the query run faster, and optimizes your overall system performance.

Comment: While this is true and already mentioned in the comments, clearly it is best not to have the spaces, but we basically don-t know where they come from and running a update query regularly would also improve the scenario. But I think that this will be early run query so that it doesn't mattet

Comment: Bug:  `'15.5.44.40' LIKE '%5.5.44.4%'` return 'true'.

Comment: No, he didn't say that he wanted  only one IP address, that he finds more with %searchstrinf% is normal

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP '\\b5\\s*.\\s*5\\s*.\\s*44\\s*.\\s*4\\b'
```

(That syntax is for MySQL 8.0; a different syntax is needed for MySQL 5 and MariaDB.)